# Jquery letter shuffle loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, jquery-animate

i'm trying to loop these shuffling sentences on my page.

I already tried using

```
function loop() {
    container.shuffleLetters({callback:loop});
}
```

and it only loop the first sentences from the html container.

But what i want is, it will loop after the last sentence finish animated.
Please check this fiddle for the certain example.

http://jsfiddle.net/4a0zwfcq/1/

And if you guys had any clue, please use my fiddle to fix it.
Would appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: Check [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/4a0zwfcq/2/). Cleaned-Up code little bit

Comment: Thanks! this one is work perfectly. but how do you reset it to the first sentence after the last one is finish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to synchronize the timeouts

1. Create an array of texts
2. Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`
3. Call separate function(`shuffle` here) to update the text with an element from array
4. When all the elements from array are finished, call the function(`last`) to animate the last default text.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/4a0zwfcq/3/)

```js
/**
 * @name  Shuffle Letters
 * @author  Martin Angelov
 * @version  1.0
 * @url   http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/shuffle-letters-effect-jquery/
 * @license  MIT License
 */

(function($) {

  $.fn.shuffleLetters = function(prop) {

    var options = $.extend({
      "step": 8, // How many times should the letters be changed
      "fps": 25, // Frames Per Second
      "text": "", // Use this text instead of the contents
      "callback": function() {} // Run once the animation is complete
    }, prop)

    return this.each(function() {
      var el = $(this),
        str = "";

      // Preventing parallel animations using a flag;
      if (el.data('animated')) {
        return true;
      }
      el.data('animated', true);

      if (options.text) {
        str = options.text.split('');
      } else {
        str = el.text().split('');
      }

      // The types array holds the type for each character;
      // Letters holds the positions of non-space characters;

      var types = [],
        letters = [];

      // Looping through all the chars of the string

      for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

        var ch = str[i];

        if (ch == " ") {
          types[i] = "space";
          continue;
        } else if (/[a-z]/.test(ch)) {
          types[i] = "lowerLetter";
        } else if (/[A-Z]/.test(ch)) {
          types[i] = "upperLetter";
        } else {
          types[i] = "symbol";
        }

        letters.push(i);
      }

      el.html("");

      // Self executing named function expression:

      (function shuffle(start) {

        // This code is run options.fps times per second
        // and updates the contents of the page element

        var i,
          len = letters.length,
          strCopy = str.slice(0); // Fresh copy of the string

        if (start > len) {

          // The animation is complete. Updating the
          // flag and triggering the callback;

          el.data('animated', false);
          options.callback(el);
          return;
        }

        // All the work gets done here
        for (i = Math.max(start, 0); i < len; i++) {

          // The start argument and options.step limit
          // the characters we will be working on at once

          if (i < start + options.step) {
            // Generate a random character at thsi position
            strCopy[letters[i]] = randomChar(types[letters[i]]);
          } else {
            strCopy[letters[i]] = "";
          }
        }

        el.text(strCopy.join(""));

        setTimeout(function() {

          shuffle(start + 1);

        }, 1000 / options.fps);

      })(-options.step);


    });
  };

  function randomChar(type) {
    var pool = "";

    if (type == "lowerLetter") {
      pool = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    } else if (type == "upperLetter") {
      pool = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    } else if (type == "symbol") {
      pool = ",.?/\\(^)![]{}*&^%$#'\"";
    }

    var arr = pool.split('');
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
  }

})(jQuery);


$(function() {
  var container = $("#container"),
    userText = $('#userText');

  // Shuffle the contents of container
  container.shuffleLetters();

  // Bind events
  userText.click(function() {
    userText.val("");
  }).bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      // The return key was pressed
      container.shuffleLetters({
        "text": userText.val()
      });
      userText.val("");
    }
  }).hide();

  // Leave a 4 second pause

  function last() {
    console.log(container);
    // Shuffle the container with custom text
    container.shuffleLetters({
      "text": "Test it for yourself!"
    });
    userText.val("type anything and hit return..").fadeIn();
  }

  var container = $("#container");

  container.shuffleLetters();

  function shuffle(text) {
    console.log(text);
    // Shuffle the container with custom text
    container.shuffleLetters({
      text: text
    });
  }

  var arr = ['TEXT 1', 'TEXT 2', 'TEXT 3', 'TEXT 4'];
  var i = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    shuffle(arr[i++ % arr.length]);
  }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">LOAD TEXT</div>
```

Comment: This code is cleaner than my code, but i need to set it back to the beginning after the last one finish. Do you have any clue?

Comment: Thanks, this is what i've been looking for! Maybe you can edit this one to your answer, so i can give a check for it. :)